# Перевод данных Buffer в JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Доброго времени суток.

Изобрёл велосипед для передачи данных между сервером с белым IP и своим компьютером, теперь надеюсь на вашу помощь)

У меня есть два приложения, которые обмениваются через сокет ( использую стандартный net модуль ) данными в JSON формате.

Короткие строки передаются без проблем, однако при передаче информации в формате **{ clientId: ...type: "data", data: [1,2,3,...] }**, где data - информация от стороннего приложения, `Buffer.toString()` получается слишком длинным, из-за чего я не могу перевести данные обратно в объект через `JSON.parse()`.

Подскажите, каким образом я могу решить данную проблему, не меняя всю структуру?

UPD1:

Код серверной части:

```
await this.socket.write(JSON.stringify({
    id, type: "data", data: data.toJSON().data
}));
```

Пример data - данные RDP подключения.

Код клиентской части:

```
server.on("data", async (data) => {
    data = JSON.parse(data.toString());
    
    ...
}
```

UPD2: Исходя из того, что информация доходит полная, но в разных чанках, написал костыль, подающий признаки жизни, о работоспособности в целом и с множеством клиентов позже отпишусь.

```
this.buffer += data.toString();

try {
    data = JSON.parse(this.buffer);
    this.buffer = "";
} catch (e) { return; }
```

Comment: При "сторонних приложений", данные которых я передаю - RDP подключение.

Comment: мы не сможем вам помочь не имея минимального кода, воспроизводящего проблему. сделайте пример: код сервера, код клиента и т.д.

Comment: Дополнил, но там ничего необычного, просто передача строки.

Comment: "получается слишком длинным" - это сколько примерно?

Comment: @Yaant даже приблизительно не считал, если честно, но так как в data я передаю массив байт, приходящий от того-же RDP например, вывод превышает максимальную вместимость строки на ноде в 2-3 раза. ( то есть при том же console.log выводится 2-3 сообщения )

Comment: @NyashMyash99 ты что-то недоговариваешь. я сейчас погонял 7мб с клиента на сервер и с сервера на клиент и у меня всё норм. сейчас выложу куда нибудь исходники

Comment: @nörbörnën благо сразу сделал логирование в файл, вот так выглядит работа программы: https://pastebin.com/NxHgmKnt

Comment: @NyashMyash99 покажи на этой кукле что нужно сделать для того чтобы повторить проблему https://github.com/norbornen/ExtralargeIckySquares. (сейчас данные швыряются с клиента на сервер. чтобы наоборот - нужно раскомментировать `hardy` в сервере, закомментировать в клиенте)

Comment: @NyashMyash99, я верю, что у тебя проблема и мне любопытно. но ты показываешь логи, которые лишь следствие какой-то настройки/ошибки. кстати, по логу видно, что данные приходят полностью, просто отдельными чанками.

Comment: @NyashMyash99 Ну, мы тут у себя давеча столкнулись с некоторыми проблемами при размере строки в 400 мегабайт. Поэтому я и заинтересовался, какие же размеры у Вас. :)

Comment: кстати, может быть на локалхосте это и не воспроизведётся, потому что нужны сетевые ограничения.короче, вот что я нашёл https://stackoverflow.com/a/40771696/4496422

Comment: @nörbörnën исходя из того, что данные вся таки доходят, но в разных чанках, сделал лютейший костыль (upd2), который подаёт признаки жизни, поэтому пока поколупаюсь в этом направлении.

Comment: @nörbörnën ну да, нормальным образом я никак не могу определить клиента до полного получения пакета, следовательно для многих не сработает..
Остаётся пытаться как-то передать всё за один раз :(
На счёт сетевых ограничений - настройки не знаю, но скорость на сервере достаточная, а вот у клиента..